# Spring HATEOAS + JPA links

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-hateoas

I have a few JPA entities, `Container` and `Thing`. `Container` has a `Thing` field.

Asking for `/container/123` will return the object `container` with id `123`, and two links: `_self` = `localhost/container/123` and `thing` = `localhost/container/123/thing`

However, when clicking on `localhost/container/123/thing`, the `_self` link for that `thing` will always be `localhost/thing/0`, which is wrong (the id should be something like `456`, but it's always `0`)

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bug in Spring Data / REST / HATEOAS?

Comment: This seems related to JPA LAZY fetching. If I mark `thing` to be `EAGER`ly fetched, everything works properly, but I don't think that's the proper solution...

Comment: Can you show some of your code?  How are you creating the links?

Comment: I'll add some code later, but it's just a normal CrudRepository, and the REST resource gets created automatically by Spring Data. Same for the links, I'm not creating them, they get created automatically

Comment: That is your issue then.  The automatic link generation probably uses `EntityLinks`, which will point to the `findOne()` method for your `thing` controller.  You are either going to have to manually create the links and/or override the default `ResourceAssembler` implementation being used.